# Facebook SDK post to page post area

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I am developing facebook appliation using php sdk v4. I am able to post facebook page using the php. But the problem is it is post to "POSTS TO PAGE" area using my account. But I need to post to page as admin. Here is my current code.

```
$page_post = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'POST', '/'. $page_id .'/feed', array(
    'access_token' => $pageAccessRoken, 
    'message' => 'This is a test message sample appplication'
) ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

Any solution?

Comment: Use a page access token. My guess is that even if you are using $pageAccessToken it is actually not a page access token

Comment: So How to get page access token? Do I need to get it externally or do I need to get it using a graph api call?

Comment: How did you get the one you use now? How to get them is explained at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/accounts'); used that code. Then I access the access_token paramerter in result. Can you give me a sample code?

Comment: But the problem is as it is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60492/discussion-between-manitaz-and-wizkid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you pass valid session and the valid page access token.

```
$page_post = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'POST', '/' . $page_id . '/feed', array(
    'access_token' => $pageAccessRoken,
    'perms' => 'ADMINISTER',
    'message' => "This is sample content"
        )))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

Comment: You mean that need to validate session before do FacebookRequest?